# Shipping Charges Calculator in Java, coming up with wrong figures

Tags: java, rounding

I am using Java and doing a shipping charges calculator based on different weights and distances. We are practicing the if-else statements but I am running into a problem I can't figure out.

When I calculate different weights and distances I am getting the wrong answers.

I think it has something to do with my math where I can't seem to get the program to add the next charge for distance because it's not using the remainder. Please help me understand this.

```
public class ShippingCharges {

private double weight;
private double miles;


public ShippingCharges (double w, double m)
{
    weight = w;
    miles = m;
}


public double getShippingCharges()
{
    double charges;
    if (weight <= 2.0)
    { charges = (1.10 * miles / 500);
    }
    else if ((weight > 2.0) && (weight <= 6.0))
    {
        charges = (2.20 * (miles  / 500 ));
    }
    else if ((weight > 6.0) && (weight <=10.0))
    {
        charges = (3.70 * (miles / 500 )); 
    }
    else 
    {
        charges = (4.80 * miles  / 500);
    }
    return charges;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect and what you get? Where do you use it?

Comment: Can you give an example of an expected output, and what you obtain instead?

Comment: Ok, its like this, for every 500 miles shipped it should add another lets say, 2.20. It seems that if the miles is, lets say, 750, it seems to be only calculating the first 500 and not adding an additional 2.20 because its over 500 miles.

Comment: Could be a double precision problem - you should really be using BigDecimal for money.

Comment: Ok, its like this. It i enter 9.5 weight and 750 miles my output is 5.55. But it should be 7.40. The shipping charges per 500 miles are not prorated. A 2 pound package at 550 would be 2.20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you said I understand the problem is you are not rounding up the miles/500 result, try this:

```
public double getShippingCharges()
{
    double charges;
    if (weight <= 2.0)
    { charges = (1.10 * Math.ceil(miles / 500));
    }
    else if ((weight > 2.0) && (weight <= 6.0))
    {
        charges = (2.20 * Math.ceil(miles  / 500 ));
    }
    else if ((weight > 6.0) && (weight <=10.0))
    {
        charges = (3.70 * Math.ceil(miles / 500 )); 
    }
    else 
    {
        charges = (4.80 * Math.ceil(miles  / 500));
    }
    return charges;

    }
```

Comment: I tried that code and it worked on the 9.5 pounds at 750 miles, but the 2 pound package at 550 miles is 2.00 instead of 2.20. I have not seen the Math.ceil before. Could you please explain what that is so I know for future use. Thanks

Comment: It rounds up a value. Are you sure its not 2.2? It should be. Maybe you copied the code before I edited the parentesis

Comment: Yep, i think I did. Thank you so much, I was going to try to use a modulus but I don't know much about those either. Thanks for all your help!!!